# row for each data value in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 tables

- beerlines (ID,beerline 1 to 12)
- pludata (customerID, pluID, pluName, pluDepartment, pluPrice)
- masterdata (masterNo, customerID)

  ```
  SELECT 
  MasterID,beerline1,beerline2,beerline3,beerline4,
  beerline5,beerline6,beerline7,beerline8,beerline9,
  beerline10,beerline11,beerline12 
  FROM `masterdata` 
  JOIN beerlines ON masterdata.masterNo = beerlines.MasterID 
  WHERE masterdata.customerNo = '23'
  ```

With this im getting all values on 1 line making it hard to output into my datatable.

i want to be able get something like this

- MasterID : beerline1 : pluName : pluDepartment
- MasterID : beerline2 : pluName : pluDepartment
- MasterID : beerline3 : pluName : pluDepartment
- MasterID : beerline4 : pluName : pluDepartment

How would i be able to get a row for each value in my beerlines table?

Comment: Sounds like your "beerlines" table could use some structural changes.  What exactly *is* a "beerline" and why does one of them have exactly 12 similarly named values?

Comment: its a hardware device with 12 different physical beerlines. I could make 12 different insert for each line if that would make more sense. i just though it would be more clever to group them at 1 line instead of 12? 

This hardware device is sending data from 1 to 12 lines (depending on how much beer they have) and each one tell what PLU (what kind of beer they are dispencing)

Comment: "More clever" isn't always a great idea.  "Simpler" usually is.  Consider modeling the objects you have... In this case it sounds like you have a "Device" which can have many "Lines".  So you'd have a table of devices, and table of lines with a FK to the device.  Displaying things on one line where necessary is a matter for the user interface, not for the data model.  The data model should be as bare and simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM masterdata m JOIN
     pludata pd
     ON pd.CustomerId = md.CustomerId JOIN
     ((SELECT bl.MasterID, 'beerline1' as which, beerline1 as beerline
       FROM beerlines bl
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT bl.MasterID, 'beerline2' as which, beerline2 as beerline
       FROM beerlines bl
      ) UNION ALL
      . . . 
     ) bl 
     ON bl.MasterId = m.masterNo
WHERE m.customerNo = 23;
```

However, you should really fix your data model.  Having multiple columns distinguished by a number is generally not a good idea.  Instead, you should have a junction table, with one row per master id and one per beer line.

Comment: so my beerlines should just be masterID - beerlineID instead and have 1 to 12 inserts and that way make the select easier ?

this database is collecting informations from many different masters.. thats why i though 1 line for each customer would make it more manageable

Comment: @SonnyHansen . . . Yes, that would be a better way to represent the data.  You may want to include a "line number" in the table, if that is important.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpivot the columns into rows, but mysql doesn't have unpivot table operator like sql server for example. But you can use `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT b.Id, b.beerline, pludata.pluDepartment
FROM masterdata
INNER JOIN
(

    SELECT ID, beerline1 AS beerline
    FROM beerlines 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, beerline2 AS beerline
    FROM beerlines 
    ...
    ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, beerline12 AS beerline
    FROM beerlines 

) AS b ON masterdata.masterNo = b.MasterID 
JOIN pludata ON masterdata.customerID = pludata.CustomerID
WHERE masterdata.customerNo = '23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following David's suggestion about making my datatable more simple the solution was much more easy to figure out.

```
SELECT MasterID,beerlines.beerline,pludata.pluNo,pludata.pluName,pludata.pluDepartment 
FROM `masterdata`
JOIN beerlines ON masterdata.masterNo = beerlines.MasterID
JOIN pludata ON pludata.pluNo = beerlines.plu AND pludata.customerNo = masterdata.customerNo
WHERE masterdata.customerNo = '23'
```

This gave me what i wanted, thanks for being so fast and help full in a matter of seconds!